# How to find all ip addresses blocked by iptables -A

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

Without meaning to do so, I probqbly block Ip Address of Googlebot using `iptables -A  INPUT -s xxx -j DROP`. That's maybe the reason why my web site is not referenced by Google.
Question: As I don't know which Ip is google's, So How to find the log of iptables and accept all Ip blocked using `iptables -D INPUT -s xxx -j DROP` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try the following command in Linux

```
iptables -L INPUT -v -n
```

You can search for specific IP by using GREP

```
iptables -L INPUT -v -n | grep "192.168.2.1"
```

Comment: Thank you i got my list.